# How to use local web application as a UI for Java?

Tags: java, html, web-applications, localhost

I've seen a lot of tutorials online on making a local web app and they all work, but I have some of my own problems that those tutorials can't seem to solve.

I'm trying to make a program of some kind and instead of using JFrame or other UI systems, I wish to use a local web app, like http://localhost:8080 in a browser

When a button is pressed or an input is submitted from a textbox, I want it to call a function from a running java program somehow.

Is this possible? If not, what are some suggestions?

Comment: Your java application would need to implement a http server and accept http requests

Comment: would the http server be accessible to anyone on that network? I might've made a mistake in my question because I saw this web app that was only accessible from the local device